# Was there a phase in Machine Learning timeline when researchers thought some Neural Networks could not be trained?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks, history

I was talking to a professor who made a comment to my question.

> Me: So much of quality literature around this topic ( IP Protection
>   for Neural Weights) emanated in 1990-1991, I'm truly at loss to
>   understand what went wrong. Why did everyone suddenly stop worrying
>   about this topic?
>
> Prof: I think AI was starved of training data and what training data
>   there was demonstrated that, depending on the architecture of the
>   Neural Network ("NN"), there would be some NN's that could not be
>   trained. They would essentially oscillate and never reach equilibrium.
>   That is where the "Deep Learning" approach solved the problem -- and
>   allowed AI/NN to move forward.

Fascinating. I looked up and indeed Deep Learning pushed forward in 2000 after it was introduced for Artificial Neural Networks by Igor Aizenberg and colleagues in 2000.

I want to collect research papers/ opinions around this point. Was AI/NN really bottlenecked until 2000 (Advent of Deep Learning)? What spurred the exponential growth in this domain?